# Solr updates are taking too long. The update requests are stalling

Tags: solr

folks! Hope you're doing well.
I have a solr cluster in cloud configured with 1 zk and 2 solr nodes. With a collection that has 1 shard and 2 replicas (one per node) configured as NRT. When i connect to zk and start to send updates (usually in batches of 100-1000 docs), the update request stalls and throws an IOException signaling that: "request processing has stalled for with remaining elements in the queue". But the docs barely have 2-3kb of average size. I'd like to have a clue about what i have to investigate.
I want to know if it can be a slow network or something intrinsic to solr that i have to investigate. Like tweak the config files to see what happens.
I can't share the solr config files, unfortunately. But one interesting thing is that the commits are done by the clients(usualy soft commits), there's no autoCommit configured.
I know there are a few related questions, but the only answer i got is to increase the threshold limit for the request to stale. But this only masks the problem, not solve him.

I appreciate any help,
Best Regards! :)

Already raised the stall threshold limit, but it only masks the slowness problem.

UPDATE: We discovered the problem. It was a field used for spatial search that holds sometimes very large polygons and lines. So we had to compress it before the index updates. Thank you.

Comment: Are you committing from each client and indexing in parallel?

Comment: No, actually there's only one app sending updates right now.

Comment: Tell us more about your Solr setup and your client setup.

* What version of Solr? How is it installed, on what hardware and where?
* Is your client app using Java and SolrJ? (since you say you connect to ZK) Are you using CloudSolrClient, HttpSolrClient, ConcurrentUpdateHttp2SolrClient or Http2SolrClient?
* What do you mean with stall? Is it the SolrJ setting `solr.cloud.client.stallTime` you refer to?
* What are your host names? Have you set `SOLR_HOST` to a FQDN? Does routing and reverse DNS work between client and solr and between solr nodes?